# How to specify default user for Jenkins (linux) to Windows slave

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

I have a Jenkins master (linux) and some windows slave. When I rdp to the windows hosts and run the git commands they use the .ssh directory to pick up the id_rsa key. However when this job is triggered from jenkins the `echo %HOME%` gives `/apps/jenkins/jenkins-1.553`. I tried using `setx HOME C:\Users\MyUser` but was unsuccessful. As a result all git commands are unsuccessful since they cannot find the private key.

How do I tell jenkins to use my user directory as the home directory?

Comment: Have you tried adding the HOME var through the GUI? (on your windows machine) it worked fine for me...

Comment: Yes it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve the issue. While settings up a jenkins slave we can explicitly define the environment variables that would be used. Setting the `HOME` variable at that point resolved the issue.

A similar problem had occurred while using the `JAVA_HOME` variable. The same workaround can be used here.

[image: A snapshot of the jenkins slave configuration]